# Doesn't hide\show few fields in Mustache template language

Tags: java, html, mustache

When using one pair of {{#......}} {{/.......}} in the source code to show/hide, then everything works just fine; when adding just one more pair (show/hide), it gives me an error:

*03-11 09:53:33.847: WARN/dalvikvm(13459): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2aacc8a0)
03-11 09:53:33.917: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13459): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.MyActivity}: 
com.samskivert.mustache.MustacheParseException: Section missing close tag 'dic' @ line 47
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2705)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2721)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:132)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2071)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:876)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:634)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: com.samskivert.mustache.MustacheParseException: Section missing close tag 'dic' @ line 47
        at com.samskivert.mustache.Mustache$Accumulator$1.finish(Mustache.java:433)
        at com.samskivert.mustache.Mustache.compile(Mustache.java:167)
        at com.samskivert.mustache.Mustache$Compiler.compile(Mustache.java:61)
        at com.samskivert.mustache.Mustache$Compiler.compile(Mustache.java:56)
        at com.example.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:130)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2669)
        ... 11 more
03-11 09:53:34.007: WARN/ActivityManager(179): Force finishing activity com.example/.MyActivity
03-11 09:53:34.007: WARN/WindowManager(179): updateFocusedWindowLocked newFocus=null mode=0 mCurrentFocus = null
03-11 09:53:34.047: WARN/WindowManager(179): updateFocusedWindowLocked newFocus=Window{300fb6b8 application Error! paused=false} mode=1 
mCurrentFocus = null
03-11 09:53:34.057: WARN/WindowManager(179): updateFocusedWindowLocked newFocus=Window{300fb6b8 Ошибка приложения! paused=false} mode=3 
mCurrentFocus = Window{300fb6b8 application Error! paused=false}
03-11 09:53:34.057: DEBUG/KeyguardViewMediator(179): setHidden false*

The line of code with error:

```
Template tmpl = Mustache.compiler().escapeHTML(false).compile(template);
```

The program code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
private final static String LOG = "WedView";
String template;
String value = "";
Boolean True = true;
Boolean False = false;

WebView mWebView;


private class ContosoWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) throws MustacheException
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Tg tg = new Tg(new Date(), "5345", "ghfg", 4455, 0.0, 0);

    Tzzz tzzz = new Tzzz(2, "", "", "", "",
            "gdfg", "fgdfgdf", "", "", "gdfgdg", "gfdf", "fgd1", 36.6, 121, "Joe ", "555-5555", "", "",
            true, false, 208.9, new Date(41, 12, 12, 13, 30),
            "hhh", "12345678", "2zzzz", "21", "", "", "", "", "", "");

    tg.Stops.add(tzzz);


    try
    {

        InputStream is = getAssets().open("DetailActivity.htm");

        template = new ReadFile().Read(is);


    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.d(LOG, " error", e);
    }

    DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##.0");

    Template tmpl = Mustache.compiler().escapeHTML(false).compile(template);
    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();


    ........................    


    value = tzzz.Value1;
    data.put("tv_stopH", value);

    value = tzzz.Value2;
    data.put("tv_sch", value);

    value = tzzz.Value3;
    data.put("arri", value);

    value = tzzz.Value4;
    data.put("tv_add", value);

    value = tzzz.Value5;
    data.put("cont", value);

    value = tzzz.Value6;
    data.put("tv_cont", value);

    if(tripStop.RefName1.length() > 0)
    {
        data.put("pic1", True);

        value = tzzz.Value7;
        data.put("tv_refName1", value);

        value = tzzz.Value8;
        data.put("tv_ref1", value);
    }

    if(tripStop.Ref1.length() > 0)
    {
        data.put("dic", True);

        value = tzzz.Value9;
        data.put("tv_refName2", value);

        value = tzzz.Value10;
        data.put("tv_ref2", value);
    }


    ......................  
    try
    {

        File file = new File("sdcard/Android/data/com.aplication/files/main.css");
        boolean success = file.createNewFile();

        BufferedWriter outfile =  new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("sdcard/Android/data/com.aplication/files/main.css"));
        outfile.write(Css_file);
        outfile.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.d(LOG, " error!", e);
    }

    String temp = tmpl.execute(data);


    mWebView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);

    // Disable scrollbars
    mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);

    // Scrollbar Overlay Content
    mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);


    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(this), "AndroidFunction");   
    mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, temp, "text/html", "utf-8", null);        
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new ContosoWebViewClient());

}
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="section3">
        <span class="section3_label1">{{tv_stopH}}</span><span class="section3_label2">    {{tv_sch}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="section3_1">
    <div class="section3_1_textblock1">
        <span class="label_alt">{{arri}}</span><br />
        {{tv_add}}
    </div>
    <div class="section3_1_textblock2">
        <span class="label_alt">{{cont}}</span><br />
        {{tv_cont}}
    </div>
    <div class="section3_1_textblock1">
        {{#pic1}}
        <span class="label_alt">{{tv_refName1}}:</span>&nbsp;{{tv_ref1}}<br />
        {{/pic1}}
        {{#dic}}
        <span class="label_alt">{{tv_refName2}}:</span>&nbsp;{{tv_ref2}}<br />
        {{/dic}}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the tv_refName2 key in the map:

Your code:

```
 if(tripStop.Ref1.length() > 0){
        data.put("dic", True);
        value = tzzz.Value9;

        data.put("tv_ref2", value); //This should probably be "tv_refName2"

        value = tzzz.Value10;
        data.put("tv_ref2", value);
  }
```